# how to make url rewiting works on read more link

Tags: php

I have read more link that shows part of the text. When clicked, it shows the rest of the text on next page. Here is my code:

```
<?php

$content = "";
$link = "linkreadmore.php";
$limit = 400;
function readMore($content,$link,$var,$id, $limit) {
    $content = substr($content,0,$limit);
    $content = substr($content,0,strrpos($content,' '));
    $content = $content." <a href='$link?$var=$id'>More...</a>";
    return $content;

 ?>
```

Now i want rewrite the URL of linkreadmore.php which lives in folder1/folder2/linkreadmore.php. Here is my rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule ^/?more/([0-9]+)$ /socialM/polip/linkreadmore.php?var=$1 [L]
```

Then, i rewrite the read more script like this.

```
<?php

$content = "";
$link = "more";
$limit = 400;
function readMore($content,$link,$var,$id, $limit) {
    $content = substr($content,0,$limit);
    $content = substr($content,0,strrpos($content,' '));
    $content = $content." <a href='/$link/=$id'>More...</a>";
    return $content;

?>
```

It shows file not found. What am I missing here?

Comment: The folder1/folder2 correspond to socialM/polip

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra `=` in the URL. This line should work instead:

```
$content = $content." <a href='/$link/$id'>More...</a>"
```

You‘re also missing a closing `}` for your function, but if the code works, that’s probably just a typo in the question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but i have tried this $content = $content." <a href='/$link/$id'>More...</a>" and it is still not working. I have the bracket } is closed as well.

Comment: @johntigana What URL do you see in the address bar?

Comment: I saw https://www.mybesite.com/more/id for example, if id=2, it will show https://www.mybesite.com/more/2

Comment: But it is still saying file not found. Is there a problem with my url rewriting?

Comment: @johntigana No, it looks good. Is this in a .htacess file? If so, is the .htacess file in the web root directory?

Comment: You can also use the `[R]` flag to show the redirect in the browser, which will give you more information to actually know what’s happening. It’s possible the not found error is actually correct.

Comment: @johntigana Great. If the answer solved your problem, you can also [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234). That way, the system recognizes that the question is answered, and you get some reputation.